# CakePHP 3 - Where put Global Functions and access on Models/Controllers?

Tags: php, function, cakephp, model, helper

I'm using CakePHP3 and have 2 questions:

- Where can i put global functions like "onlyNumbers()", returning only numbers from string. i'll use this function in controllers and entities.
- How can I insert a modify value in DB different of the user input? Lets take a example: I have a input field(like zip code), with js mask like: **xxxxx-xxx**, and when user send it, cakephp receive the string with the dots and dash. I want to insert to DB only numbers.

I don't know if it's right, but I think adding to entity the "_setZipCode()" function and do the string modification directly works, but how I would access the "onlyNumbers()" global function?

Thanks!

Comment: You can put the function in your applications bootstrap.php

Comment: In cake you can add model methods to your `AppModel.php` file which will then be accessible in any model by `$this->myMethod()` and and controller by `$this->Model->myMethod();`

Same goes for `AppController.php`, but this will only be accessible by controllers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use 'Components'

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components.html

in **src/Controller/Components/GlobalComponent.php**

```
namespace App\Controller\Component;

use Cake\Controller\Component;

class GlobalComponent extends Component
{
    public function onlyNumbers($string)
    {

       //Do something to get numbers or what you want

       return $result;
    }
}
```

load component in **YourController** or in **AppController** if you want have golbal access

```
class YourController extends Controller
{

    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this -> loadComponent('Global');
    }


    public function yourAction()
    {

       $only_numbers = $this -> Global -> onlyNumbers('ABC123BCA');

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Where can i put global functions like "onlyNumbers()", returning only numbers from string. i'll use this function in controllers and entities.

This sounds like you want to do validation, which should be done inside a validator. [See this link](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html#adding-validation-providers).

If you *really* need a global function put it in bootstrap.php but I would stay OOP and put the code into the right place and context.

> How can I insert a modify value in DB different of the user input? Lets take a example: I have a input field(like zip code), with js mask like: xxxxx-xxx, and when user send it, cakephp receive the string with the dots and dash. I want to insert to DB only numbers.

This *is* validation. Have you read this chapter of the official documentation?

- http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html
- http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/validation.html

There are already two, maybe three rules that you could use for your usecase:

- http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.Validation.Validation.html#_numeric
- http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.Validation.Validation.html#_isInteger
- http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.Validation.Validation.html#_range